# claims not found on client side

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have implemented IDS4 client. Here is the code to register client on IDS4 in **config.cs**

```
new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "HR.WebClient",
                    ClientName = "HR Module Web Client",
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("****".Sha256()) },

                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
                    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,

                    // removed some code for brevity

                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                    RequireConsent =  false,

                    // removed some code for brevity
                },
```

and here is an extension method I am using to configure my client in the **startup.cs** of my client app.

```
public static void AddCustomAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration Configuration)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = $"{Configuration["ClientId"]}.Cookie";
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options => 
            {
                options.Authority = Configuration["IdentityServerUri"];
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                options.ClientId = Configuration["ClientId"]; 
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["ClientSecret"]; 
                options.ResponseType = "code";

                options.SaveTokens = true;
                
                // get claims
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                // removed some code for brevity

            });

            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        }
```

**PROBLEM**

I have written some server side logic to add claims on run time. I can also see those claims on server application side.
[image]

But I am unable to see any claims on client side.

[image]

What am I missing?

**Update**

here is the sample of my id_token and access_token

**.Token.id_token**
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkNGN0U3OUJEMjNENUFEQjdCQkFFNkM2Mzk3NjM0RTBBIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJuYmYiOjE2NDA2NzA0NDUsImV4cCI6MTY0MDY3MDc0NSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTAwMSIsImF1ZCI6IkNvcnBMZW5zZS5IUi5XZWJDbGllbnQiLCJpYXQiOjE2NDA2NzA0NDUsImF0X2hhc2giOiJUWVdkd2lCbEdacHoyQ19FcXBZaXFBIiwic3ViIjoiNDJkNjRkNzQtMDBjMC00MmE5LWI1OWEtNTUyYjcwOGM0NTcxIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNjQwNTkwMTQzLCJpZHAiOiJsb2NhbCIsInByZWZlcnJlZF91c2VybmFtZSI6ImlmdGlraGFyIiwibmFtZSI6ImlmdGlraGFyIiwiYW1yIjpbInB3ZCJdfQ.LgS2_-yW9XcMqmZhOhbSdMznpmbUvat_e7mfw8YLajCOjREuECvYlyC2nowlu6Khch2FZyM5RAgqYPHc0db2NBxhLEaqNIwWIa9We32Vdy6wrHPkx1TrGkQymoiXcktkIeaNA1TCMUfSDA1XRbfygfPyFCq9t06CHC4WmVmcdQFavXic_jFCEBV45_qGsuAeqYi0qbStoQd3dWqkhOkBg3aiZjZKycQXTWGb-dBFSIG7xFZx2AhsEYBpTI9NzG3oRbYbJlV-CEuV2umFVdX77zZOdSvvdrRiMzN_XLw8ZWysLG5yAJiIkL-dprKhqTUbtUHw1jkq4VZc-iQUNvsOgw

**.Token.access_token**
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkNGN0U3OUJEMjNENUFEQjdCQkFFNkM2Mzk3NjM0RTBBIiwidHlwIjoiYXQrand0In0.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.kOipzf-kUNSviqgoRf8ieZtswAc6eBfMlkvuc44qNaKAzUIr8Bv4J6O0X455ctnh-jJrutvVkUsBu0SS-wBllAS7LUGh2aIhJV9qTgITxKvDchfHrzJnpyI3dGEbmUweC0pqvpzM_KDNKUG-GhafthehEz6V1SYq3DA2XPKevO4xuTAF9R9zl4KtgXVPZQba2A-3GZxOuL2WZhcxYV3Qm3kLQlHHxiriz5vQDIXTIYsmRdh791YDsjHr7lKIG9Vf8b2Mddivs8FFZerJAJzanzzZQ2wa0nJ4DpOQaasbBAf9NCltkUavHp7Q6x0KWPKAh5Nv--mF1A3VZOPjWvn3yg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the input from [Tore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68490/tore-nestenius) I was able to realize my ignorance. I was completely unaware of the fact the we can extend Identity Server with implementation of IProfileService. I was able to add custom claims in access_token by implementing ProfileService.

Answer (score 1):

By default, only these claims are propagated from the ID token to the User object:

```
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("sub", "sub");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("name", "name");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("given_name", "given_name");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("family_name", "family_name");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("profile", "profile");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("email", "email");
```

You can find the source [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authentication/OpenIdConnect/src/OpenIdConnectOptions.cs)

To get additional claims mapped, we have to manually map them using:

```
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("website", "website");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("gender", "gender");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("birthdate", "birthdate");
```

or

```
options.ClaimActions.MapAllExcept("iss", "nbf", "exp", "aud", "nonce");
```

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail
about this topic: [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: I have added following line to my startup.cs `options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("permission", "permission");` but still i am unable to see permission claim being propagated to client side. I can however see it on the server side.

Comment: what do you mean you see it server side? can you post a sample copy of the ID and access JWT token? also?  Do you mean in the client or in the API ? or in JavaScript?

Comment: if I inspect the authentication cookie on the IdentityServer client implementation I can see that "permission" has been added in claims. [view IDS4 screenshot](https://ibb.co/Fh8K76g)
And if I inspect the authentication cookie on the client app which is authenticating with IDS4, I do not see any "permission" claims. [view client app screenshot](https://ibb.co/q7f8vvs)
click [here](https://www.file.io/download/tUpmnb1hZLwd) to view token data

Comment: Feel free to paste a sample id-token in the question (the download did not work). What is in the IDS4 cookie is not of any interest here, the main importance is what is actually inside the ID-token and what is available trough the UserInfo endpoint. Do you see the permission in the userinfo endpoint?

Comment: I have updated the question with my sample id_token and access_token

Comment: What claims do you se in your client? Are you looking for the permission claim? the permission claim is not in any of the tokens, are you sure its available through the UserInfo endpoint?

Comment: UserInfo endpoint only returns following data 
`{
    "sub": "42d64d74-00c0-42a9-b59a-552b708c4571",
    "preferred_username": "iftikhar",
    "name": "iftikhar"
}` and yes I want to see **permission** claim

Comment: But if you don't see the claim in the tokens or at the UserInfo endpoint, then you have a problem with your IdentityServer configuration, I assumed your problem was in the client or API?  how have you configured the users and mapped the UserClaims to it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you have the scopes registered.

```
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "service.client",
                ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },

                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                AllowedScopes = { "api1", "api2.read_only","otherclaims/scopes" }
            }
```

Comment: yes the scopes are registered properly.

Comment: does 'HumanResourceApi' contains the claims that you need to show, if not you should add them or add the claims in the scopes directly like "openid profile email givenname etc".